# Is the integral $\int\cos(x-x^2) \;dx$ possible?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I thought of this integral:
$$\int\cos(x-x^2) \;dx,$$ but only got it down to something like this: $$\frac{1}{2}\int e^{\sqrt{x^2-x}} \;dx + \frac{1}{2}\int e^{-\sqrt{x^2-x}} \;dx.$$
I put it into wolfram alpha and it said no results. Can anyone solve it?

Comment: No, the integral is not possible

Comment: Most integrals you just "think of" will not be possible.

Comment: Why do you post this... just some random integral?

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica* gives:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) C\left(\frac{2 x-1}{\sqrt{2 \pi
   }}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) S\left(\frac{2 x-1}{\sqrt{2 \pi
   }}\right)\right)$$

Comment: And S and C are...? Fresnel integrals?

Answer (score 0):

$\cos (x-x^2) = \cos (x^2-x)=\cos (x^2-x +1/4 -1/4)$

$\int \cos ((x-1/2)^2)\cos(1/4)+\sin ((x-1/2))^2 \sin (1/4) dx$

$u=x-1/2$.

$\int \cos u^2 \cos(1/4) + \sin u^2 \sin(1/4)du$

After that Wolfram gives a result for $\int \cos(x^2) dx$ and such.

Not really much to go on from there. Maybe Taylor Series?

.

Answer (score 0):

Making it more general
$$I=\int \cos(a x^2+bx+c)\,dx$$
$$ax^2+bx+c=\left(\sqrt{a} x+\frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right)^2+\frac{4 a c-b^2}{4 a}$$
Let
$$\sqrt{a} x+\frac{b}{2 \sqrt{a}}=t \implies x=\frac{2 \sqrt{a} t-b}{2 a}\implies dx=\frac{dt}{\sqrt{a}}$$ and $d=\frac{4 a c-b^2}{4 a}$

$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int \cos(t^2+d)\,dt$$  Expand the cosine to face Fresnel integrals.

Back to $x$
$$I=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2a}} \left(\cos \left(\frac{b^2-4ac}{4 a}\right) C\left(\frac{2 a
   x+b}{ \sqrt{2 \pi a }}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{b^2-4ac}{4
   a}\right) S\left(\frac{2 a x+b}{\sqrt{2 \pi a
   }}\right)\right)$$